# Google Analytics site internal search tracking is not working on Google Site

Tags: google-analytics, google-sites

I am using Google Analytics to keep tracking on the internal search term in the site I built with "Google Site"

I have already set up the query parameter in the Google Analytics view setting. However, the internal search term tracking is not working as expected.

I searched over hundreds of keyword in the site while only 2 of them got recorded in Google Analytics.

Is there anyone who knows where the problem is?

The URL of my site is :
https://sites.google.com/mydomain

When I searched something through the searching bar in the site, the URL became:
https://sites.google.com/search/mydomain?query=something&universe=classic&scope=organization
("/search" got inserted into the URL)

I was wondering if the change of URL is the reason why search term tracking not working, but then I checked the only 2 records I got in the GA, they are like:

1. /search/mydomain?query=Test&universe=classic&scope=site&showTabs=false
2. mydomain?query=API

Dont know where 2 came from... isnt there supposed to be a "/search" in the URL when using site internal search bar in the Google Site? This also confused me a lot.

Comment: Show tour settings and an URL example, pls

Comment: @MichelePisani thanks for the comment, can you tell me what do you mean about tour settings? And about URL example, Ive added it to the problem description.

Comment: Typo... tour=your